# SSRS report shows #value Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using an Expression

```
=IIF(sum(Fields!Target.Value)=0,0,
(sum(Fields!Achievement.Value)/sum(Fields!Target.Value))*100)
```

but i want  `divide(200/0)*100 ="NAN"` but it show me `#Value Error`

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Did you build this from scratch or did you use the built in expression creator. Also you aren't actaully asking a question.

Comment: You can't divide by 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like another condition you can nest IIF inside IIF statement is that what you ae asking??

Comment: I think this should be in comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested IIF to solve this in expression but for me it's quite a mess.

This is another way to solve your problem using report code.

In the Menu go to Report > Report Properties > Code and paste the code below

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal numerator As double, ByVal denominator As double)
If IsNothing(denominator) Or denominator = 0
  Return "NaN" 
Else
  Return (numerator/denominator) * 100
End If
End Function
```

Now you could use this in your expression like this

```
=Code.Divider(sum(Fields!Achievement.Value),sum(Fields!Target.Value))
```

Note: You could change "NaN" to 0 if you want it another way around.

reference: http://williameduardo.com/development/ssrs/ssrs-divide-by-zero-error/

UPDATE:

I notice in your picture your output in Variance column is not `0` its `0.00`. Is that just that a format in SSRS? or that's the actual output? If `0.00` is the actual output then you should use `If IsNothing(denominator) Or denominator = 0.00` in report code of my answer. And also it could be the problem in your expression.